# Fetching photos dynamically?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, css

I am trying to integrate a JavaScript photo album in ASP.NET (C#).
The code which I have uses hardcoded images; I want to fetch those images dynamically.

```
 <div class="image_stack" style="margin-left:300px">
   <img id="photo1" class="stackphotos" src="photos/4.jpg"  >
   <img  id="photo2" class="stackphotos" src="photos/5.jpg" >
   <img  id="photo3" class="stackphotos"  src="photos/6.jpg" > 
 </div>
```

I want to replace these hardcoded photos with 3 URLs fetched from a database. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way:

use ASP:Image control

```
 <asp:Image ID="photo1" class="stackphotos" runat="server" ImageUrl=" " />  
 <asp:Image ID="photo2" class="stackphotos" runat="server" ImageUrl=" " />  
 <asp:Image ID="photo3" class="stackphotos" runat="server" ImageUrl=" " />
```

then you can assign ImageUrl on the server Side i.e.

```
var obj= GetUserImages(); //method fetching image urls from db.
photo1.ImageUrl = obj.ImageUrl1;
photo2.ImageUrl = obj.ImageUrl2;
photo3.ImageUrl = obj.ImageUrl3;
```

`2`.  you can simply place `runat="server"` attribute on your existing img tags and access them on the server side and set their url. i.e place runat="server" on your img like below

```
<img id="photo1" runat="server" class="stackphotos" src="photos/4.jpg"  >
```

and then   access this on server side like

```
photo1.Src = dbObject.Url;
```

`3`. you can dynamically insert imgs from the server side in a loop.

```
string imgs = string.Empty;
foreach(var item in GetAllUserImages())
{
     images +="<img src='"+ item.ImageUrl +"' class='stackphotos' />";
}
div1.InnerHtml= images;
```

where div is

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
</div>
```

`4`. you can call a `webmethod` (a method on your .aspx.cs page, marked with attribute `[WebMethod]` and  call it via ajax and update your img tags in a javascript function.

Comment: Can you elaborate the second way?

Comment: I tried the 2nd method but it did not work. Now i am trying the first method but it seems that effect jquery effect is not working anymore this is the album i am trying to integrate..
http://youhack.me/demo/g%20plus%20photo/

Comment: wait? why it didn't work? possible the relative url that you specified is wrong. open the page in google chrome, inspect element, go to console and see the errors, it must be showing 404 error, image not found. correct your relative urls i.e. prefix ~/ or ../ or remove.

Comment: <img  id="photo1" class="stackphotos"  runat="server" src="~/Images/3.jpg" >
THe moment i apply runat="server". It ceases to work.

Comment: server controls resolve relative address differently. go to the console and see what wrong url is it making. correct that by making src='../Images/3.jpg' if your Images folder is in the root of the website. see there is nothing much to this problem @Arbaaz. just tuck the urls and you wil be good to go

Comment: OK i am able to get the image from database (using 2nd method) but the hover effect isnt working anymore, i dont know why? You have been very helpful i have voted +1 already if you can help me  make the hover effect work i will mark your answer. It seems that when i apply runat="server' Jquery stops working.

Comment: jQuery? ohh. see when you apply runat="server" attribute to any control, it becomes server control, and hence its id is changed. you must be picking your images by their id in jQuery code, which no longer exists, so instead of doing `$('#photo1')` , do `$('#' + '<%= photo1.ClientID %>')`

Comment: or, if you don't want the id to change , simply place an attribute `clientidmode="static"`  on your img tags i.e. `<img id="photo1" runat="server" class="stackphotos" src="photos/4.jpg" clientidmode="static"  >`

Comment: adding 'clientidmode="static"' worked!! You are a genius bro!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
other page content
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myimages" />
other page content
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
using(var db = new myDataContext()) // see linq to sql / entity framework
   foreach(var i in db.ImagesTable.Select(img => new { Id = img.Id }))  // ImagesTable is the name of your table with info about your images
      myimages.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<img src=""myimgdir/" + i.Id + "".jpg" class=""stackphotos"" />")); // presuming that images are named according to an id in the database

}
```